# How to make ng-bootstrap typeahead show dropdown results with a link

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular7, ng-bootstrap, typeahead

I can't get the results from my songs service to show in my ng-bootstrap typeahead results. I am getting the error: "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

I have tried following the wikipedia example on the ng-bootstrap site: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#http

My .ts file has:

```
formatter = (x: { title: string }) => x.title;

  searchSongTitles = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
text$.pipe(
  debounceTime(800),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  tap(() => this.loadingNavbarSearchSongs$ = true),
  switchMap(term =>
    this.songsService.getSongsQuickSearch(term, this.titleMatchType$, this.sort$, this.sortDirection$).pipe(
      tap(() => this.loadingNavbarSearchSongsFailed$ = false),
      catchError(() => {
        this.loadingNavbarSearchSongsFailed$ = true;
        return of([]);
      })
    )
  ),
  tap(() => this.loadingNavbarSearchSongs$ = false)
)
```

and my .html file has:

```
<input id="songtitles-search" placeholder="Song Title" type="text" 
class="form-control form-control-sm my-sm-0 mr-sm-2" 
name="song_titles_search" [(ngModel)]="songTitlesSearchText$" 
[ngbTypeahead]="searchSongTitles" [resultFormatter]="formatter" 
[inputFormatter]="formatter">
```

The model:
songsService.getSongsQuickSearch returns an 
    `Observable<Song[]>`
where Song has these properties: 
    id: number;
    title: string;

I need to take the array of songs coming from the getSongsQuickSearch method so they are clickable song title links in the dropdown that link to the song details page based on its id. For example:

`<a [routerLink]="['/song-details', song.id]">{{ song.title }}</a>`

Comment: Can you please create a demo of it and share a link here?

Comment: As I posted it's just like the wikipedia example on the typeahead components examples section of the ng-bootstrap website here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#http My problem is very similar to this one but trying their fix did not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237768/ng-bootstrap-typeahead-how-to-handle-observableperson-rather-than-observabl

Comment: Can you post your `SongsService` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using ng-bootstrap typeahead with a custom response view. This is using Angular "^7.0.1" with "bootstrap": "^4.1.3" and @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.3.1"

Here is the custom CSS I used to make the search results show under the search input:

```
#search-results {
    position: absolute;
    width: 160px; /*How wide the results are*/
    background: white;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    max-height: 500px; /* How far down the results will show */
    overflow-y: auto; /* Show scrollbar if results overflow vertically */
    overflow-x: none; /* Do not show scrollbar horizontally if results overflow */
    border: 1px solid gray;
    left: 150px; /*Where from the left side of the screen the results container starts*/
    right: 0;
    top: 44px; /*Make the results container show under search input*/
}
```

Here is the search view:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <input id="songtitles-search" placeholder="Song Title" type="text" class="navbar- 
    search form-control form-control-sm my-sm-0 mr-sm-2" name="song_titles_search" 
    [(ngModel)]="songTitlesSearchText$" [ngbTypeahead]="searchSongTitles">
    <ul id="search-results" class="list-group">
        <li *ngIf="loadingNavbarSearchSongs$" class="list-group-item">
            <img class="small-image" style="width:8em; height:8em;" 
            src="assets/img/loading.gif" />
        </li>
        <li *ngFor="let song of songs$" class="list-group-item">
            <a (click)="songSearchResultChosen()" [routerLink]="['/song-details', 
            song.id]">{{ song.title }}</a> - {{song.main_main_artist}}
        </li>
        <li *ngIf="showNoSearchResultsMessage$">
            <strong>No Song(s) Found Matching Search Criteria</strong>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm my-2 my-sm-0 mr-sm-2" type="submit">
        Search
    </button>
</form>
```

Here is the typescript typeahead code:

```
searchSongTitles = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
text$.pipe(
  debounceTime(800),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  map(term => {
    this.songs$ = [];
    this.showNoSearchResultsMessage$ = false;
    if (term.length > 0) {
      this.songTitlesSearchText$ = term;
      this.getSongs();
    } else {
      this.loadingNavbarSearchSongs$ = false;
    }
  }
  )
)
```

Here is the getSongs method which calls a service I have setup

```
getSongs() {
  this.loadingNavbarSearchSongs$ = true;

  this.songsService.getSongsQuickSearch(this.songTitlesSearchText$, this.titleMatchType$,
    this.sort$, this.sortDirection$).subscribe(
    response => {
      this.songs$ = response.songs;
      this.loadingNavbarSearchSongs$ = false;
      if (this.songs$.length <= 0) {
        this.showNoSearchResultsMessage$ = true;
      }
    }
  );
}
```

You can see a working example in the navbar at my website abovetempo.com
Hope this helps someone else who is looking for this solution!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use an ng-template. I would add this as just a comment but I don't have enough reputation. Hopefully it can help others looking for the same solution.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#template